# Entity Framework cross columns group by

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, count, unpivot

I have a table of dogs and breeds which every breed name has 3 temperaments that looks like this:

```
    NAME    |    TEMP1    |    TEMP2    |    TEMP3
------------+-------------+-------------+------------
   Check1   |   Angry     |     Shy     |    Ugly
   Check2   |   Rude      |    Cute     |    Shy
   Check3   |    Bla      |    Angry    |    Smelly
```

And I want a result that crosses the temperaments columns and grouping them into this:

```
  Temp   |   COUNT(*)
---------+------------
 Shy     |      2
Angry    |      2
.
.
.
```

And if it's possible it would be great if you can answer this post using Entity Framework (if not it's okay to write it in SQL and I will convert it (if possible) to Entity Framework).

Thanks alot!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: sql-server, postgresql, mysql...?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL databases that support lateral joins (such as SQL Server, Postgres or Oracle), you would typically unpivot with a lateral join, then aggregate:

```
select x.tmp, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross apply (values (temp1), (temp2), (temp3)) x(tmp)
group by x.tmp
```

In Postgres, the syntax is `cross join lateral` instead of `cross apply`.

In other databases, you can unpivot with `union all` (this is less efficient because it requires multiple table scans):

```
select x.tmp, count(*) cnt
from (
    select temp1 tmp from mytable
    union all select temp2 from mytable
    union all select temp2 from mytable
) x
group by x.tmp
```

Comment: It works!
But do you know how to convert it to Entity Framework?

Comment: @TalS: no, I don't know about Entity Framework. You mentioned that a pure SQL solution was an acceptable option for you, so I answered with SQL, that I know about.

Comment: I tried to convert it to Entity Framework but I can't manage to.
If someone can help it would be awesome.